# String mutation in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string-matching

I want to remove all the `Mr.`s in the following array:

```
array("John Samplename", "Mr. Josh Nowitzki", "Rose Bane");
```

So I'll only have the names, without the titles.

How do I have to code it such that I get the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [array_map](http://php.net/array-map) with [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace):

```
$myAry = array("John Samplename", "Mr. Josh Nowitzki", "Rose Bane");

$myAry = array_map(function($value) {
    return trim(str_replace("Mr.", "", $value));
}, $myAry);

print_r($myAry);
```

Will print:

```
Array
(
    [0] => John Samplename
    [1] => Josh Nowitzki
    [2] => Rose Bane
)
```

---

So, `array_map` will help you to iterate through the array and `str_replace` will replace your unwanted characters. If you also want to replace `Mrs.`, you can replace `return trim(str_replace("Mr.", "", $value));` with `return trim(str_replace(["Mr.","Mrs."], "", $value));`